# How to compare time between two variables

Tags: powershell, variables, time, compare

I am trying to compare the time difference between two variables.  `$dt` is a string pulled from the text of a log file.  `$curtime` is pulled from the current date and time.

If I output `$dt`, it displays correctly the date and time from the log files.  If I output `$curtime`, it displays correctly the date and time from the workstation.

But when I try and run `New-TimeSpan` and output the difference, my response is always "02:24:12".

Here is the code I am using:

```
New-TimeSpan $dt $curtime | Set-Variable -Name $TimeDiff
if ($TimeDiff.Seconds -lt 0) }
    $Hrs = ($TimeDiff.Hours) + 23
    $Mins = ($TimeDiff.Minutes) + 59
    $Secs = ($TimeDiff.Seconds) + 59 }
else {
    $Hrs = $TimeDiff.Hours
    $Mins = $TimeDiff.Minutes
    $Secs = $TimeDiff.Seconds }
$Difference = '{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}' -f $Hrs,$Mins,$Secs
$Difference
```

Comment: _Variable $dt is a string_. You need to convert that string to a DateTime object first. Depending on the format of the string, you can use `[DateTime]::Parse()` or `[DateTime]::ParseExact()` for instance. See the methods of [DateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: So when I try and Parse or ParseExact, using $dt = datetime]::ParseExact($dt,"MM-dd-yy HH:mm:ss",$null), i get an error "Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."  When I call my $dt and $dt2, i get the exact same text and formatting:  05/30/19 08:23:37

Comment: The elements of your date are seperated by slashes rather than dashes so you need to use $dt = [DateTime]::ParseExact($dt,"MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss",$null)

Answer (score 0):

Unless he datetime from the logs are from a very narrow timespan,
it makes IMO no sense to manipulate by adding 23:59:59.
Better take the integer part from .TotalHours

Here returning hours > 24/99

```
$dt       = "05/26/19 08:23:37"
$LogDT    = [datetime]::parseexact($dt,"MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss",[cultureInfo]::Invariantculture)
$TimeDiff = [datetime]::now - $LogDT
$Difference = '{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}' -f ([math]::floor($Timediff.TotalHours)),
                                        $Timediff.Minutes,$Timediff.Seconds
```

Sample output:

```
> $Difference
111:16:17
```

Comment: Yes, the datetime from the log files will be minutes and hours.  So let me work thru this from the start.  The raw data from my log file is 05/30/19 14:01:02.  Double Day, military time with double digits regardless.  I pull the data from the log file using this script:  $regdt = '\b\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,4}\ \d{1,2}\:\d{1,2}\:\d{1,2}\b'
select-string -Path $input_path -Pattern $regdt -AllMatches | % {$_.Matches} | %{$_.Value} | Set-Variable -Name dt    My output of dt comes out as 05/30/19 14:01:02.  When I run what you posted above, my $LogDT comes out as   Sunday, May 26, 2019  8:23:37

Comment: Yes, that's your local output format, but it is of \[datetime\] **type** and can simply be subtracted from another datetime to return a timespan.

Comment: Cannot convert value "05/30/19 16:36:30" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."
At line:28 char:1
+ $TimeDiff = $curtime - $dt

Comment: How did you obtain $curtime? It also has to be of \[datetime\] type.

Comment: $curtime = Get-Date -UFormat "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S"

Comment: With `-UFormat` it is a string again, **NOT**  a [datetime].